# Strongly Typed @User.Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, strong-typing, custom-view, iidentity

I customize `IIdentity` and `IPrincipal` adding a few more properties in `IIdentity`.

You can obtain a strongly typed instance `@User.Identity` for my custom class? Without having to make conversions in cast.

I thought of something like razor customize the View, but do not even know where to start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try creating an extension method on `IPrincipal`

```
public static class PrincipalExtensions
{
    public static MyIdentity GetMyIdentity (this IPrincipal principal)
    {
        return principal.Identity as MyIdentity;
    }
}
```

and then get your identity by calling `@User.GetMyIdentity()`

Answer (score 3):

You could create a new base type for your views and add to it a property or method that will do the casting. That way you can avoid doing it all the time in your views.

Comment: also did not understand "Fin ruin"; Where can I find a good article explaining how to customize my ViewBase (based on the razor) ?

Comment: @adrift sorry, some weird typo on my part. Meant "method".